# What kind of a power supply is this and how can a standard ATX PSU be hacked to replace it?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, power

I need to replace the power supply of a newer HP Pavilion system for an emergency situation. The power supply has been damaged, but unfortunately it seems that all replacement delivery estimates are at least 1-2 months from China.

The power supply has 3 connector types coming from it: (2 ATX12V 4-pin CPU power style cables and 1 3-pin control cable)
[image: 3 cables psu]

I have adapters for an ATX power supply to provide the necessary 2 4-pin style male outputs to the motherboard, but what is really throwing me off is the 3 pin "P2" control. It appears that black is PS-ON, grey is PSU ID and black is ground.

Is it possible to take these 3 pins from an ATX PSU and connect them to these 3 cables in order to provide the appropriate functionality to make it work properly until a replacement PSU arrives in a couple months?

Also, what's the style name (if there is one specifically) for this new kind of seemingly HP proprietary PSU type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's probably a [12 V-only supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_supply_unit_(computer)#12_V%E2%80%93only_supplies) with an unusual plug design.

If you're brave and desperate, you could try using wires to connect the equivalent pins on the ATX main connector. The colors seem to match:

- Yellow to Yellow (12V)
- Green to Green (PS_ON)
- Grey to Grey (PWR_OK)
- Black to Black (GRND)

Comment: That's great to know. I was afraid about the "PSU ID" vs "PWR_OK", but this sounds reasonable. Thanks!!! Looks like a great opportunity for some cable makers to make a killing adapting this over since the darn HP units are so hard to get and take so LONG to get!